# Razor syntax for field id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How could you implement this syntax using Razor?

```
id="btnDelete@item.ID"
```

I tried id=@:btnDelete@item.ID but it didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Razor thinks it's an email address.

You need to write `btnDelete@(item.ID)`

Comment: Hidden surprises in otherwise reasonable languages ftl